# Как убрать текст из вертикального расположения поделиться от Яндекс?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Как убрать текст из вертикального расположения поделиться от Яндекс? Если использовать в отображении data-direction со значением vertical то иконки соцсетей становятся вертикально и к ним спава появляется еще их название. Например, на ровне со значком Вконтакте справа есть надпись Вконтакте, рядом со значком Фейсбук справа надпись Фейсбук и т.д. Хотелось бы понять как сделать чтоб было только значки, без текста справа.

Comment: У меня есть ответ

Comment: @Виктор, голосуйте за открытие, если у вас ответ есть.

Comment: @Visman а как это сделать?

Comment: @Виктор, хм, видимо у вас баллов не хватает. Два человека уже проголосовало за переоткрытие, так что, думаю, откроют вопрос скоро.

Comment: Пока вопрос заблокирован, оставлю ответ в комментариях. Дело в том, что Яндекс подменяет класс `ya-share2__title`, когда мы добавляем `data-direction`. Не знаю почему, но это происходит. Все лечится, если вручную переопределить стили класса. Пример тут: http://codepen.io/dukeimg/pen/dpBVJP

Comment: Виктор, благодарю Вас! все получилось отлично! но для мобильной версии тоже стало вертикально, что на телефонах смотрится не очень хорошо!

Comment: Вот что у меня было для мобильно версиии

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.ya-share2{ position:relative!important;
width: 50px!important;
height: 200px!important;
left:20%!important;
 }

Comment: но теперь тоже вертикально.. не могли бы вы мне подсказать как для мобильно версии сделать блок горизоньальным посреди экрана? сайт oscard.ru

Comment: @Виктор подскажете?

Comment: Лучше тогда ловите разрешение экрана и, отталкиваясь от него, присваивайте 'data-direction="horizontal"'. Можете ловить на $(document).ready(), а можете на $(window).resize(), тут уже в зависимости от задачи. Но для последнего варианта я бы порекомендовал использовать отложенное исполнение. Его реализации уже много раз обсуждались на SO.

Comment: @Виктор у меня мало знаний, очень мало. прошу помогите с кодом для горизонтального отображения на мобильных устройствах что бы вставить в custom.css а позицию попытаюсь сам подобрать. самостоятельно не справлюсь..

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что Яндекс подменяет класс `ya-share2__title`, когда мы добавляем `data-direction`. Не знаю почему, но это происходит. Все лечится, если вручную переопределить стили класса.

```
.ya-share2__title {
  display: none !important;
}
```

[Демонстрация](http://codepen.io/dukeimg/pen/dpBVJP)